# How to calculate date frequency in bigquery for purchase history

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, frequency

I have the following table structure:

```
email | date  | YEAR

antrim@8qwh37kibb6ut7.ml  | 2018-10-25   | 2018    
asam@bpvi.ml              | 2018-02-15   | 2018   
client5@test.com          | 2018-04-14   | 2018      
antrim@8qwh37kibb6ut7.ml  | 2017-07-19   | 2017      
client4@test.com          | 2017-09-30   | 2017         
asam@bpvi.ml              | 2017-01-25   | 2017        
antrim@8qwh37kibb6ut7.ml  | 2017-10-25   | 2017        
asam@bpvi.ml              | 2016-10-25   | 2016        
antrim@8qwh37kibb6ut7.ml  | 2016-05-17   | 2016
```

First I need the customers that only bought on the three years, the ones that repeated. So for that I did a self join three times although I suspect is not the most efficient

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT first_year.email) as repetidos
 FROM `table` AS first_year
 JOIN `table` AS second_year
  ON first_year.email = second_year.email
 JOIN `table` AS third_year
  ON first_year.email = third_year.email
 AND first_year.year = 2016
 WHERE second_year.year = 2017
 AND third_year.year = 2018
```

And this gives me the emails of the people who have bought on the three years. Like so

```
email

antrim@8qwh37kibb6ut7.ml  
asam@bpvi.ml
```

I need to know the frequency in days, meaning, If you have bought 5 times in the store I need to know the frequency of your purchases, if you buy every 40 days, every 20 days and so, I found this

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(DATE '2018-02-20', DATE '2018-01-15', DAY) as days_diff;
```

But what I don't know how to do is use that formula with my previous query. Is that possible? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please define "frequency in days".

Comment: Hi, I need to know if you bought on 2018-11-20 and 2018-11-10 and 2018-11-01 you buy every 10 days. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want:

```
SELECT t.email,
       DATE_DIFF(MAX(date), MIN(date), day) / NULLIF(COUNT(*) - 1, 0) as avg_date_diff
FROM `table` t
WHERE t.year IN (2016, 2017, 2018)
GROUP BY t.email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.year) = 3
```

Comment: Gordon, thank you. This is really helpful, this query is a lot better than what I had. And what this gives me is really good because it gives me my oldest customers. But I need to know if someone bought 5 times, if they buy every 40 days or 30 days or every 200 days. Again, thank you!

Comment: @SaúlSolórzano: `avg_date_diff` returns exactly what you want, there's no need to do an average of *days between* :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon! That's awesome! the only thing is that `COUNT(*) -1` need to have parentheses, otherwise the result is not corred.

`DATE_DIFF(MAX(date), MIN(date), day) / (COUNT(*) - 1) as avg_date_diff`

Comment: @SaúlSolórzano . . . It should really have `NULLIF()` (which is now there) to prevent division by zero.  Strictly speaking this is not necessary because of the `HAVING` clause, but I prefer to have it.  My thought process was:  put in `NULLIF()`, look at `HAVING` clause, see that `NULLIF()` not necessary, totally forget about `- 1`.  I saw that and fixed it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I understand! Thank you so much for taking the time and for the explanation! Thanks!!